# Hp Loadrunner / virtual user generator web click and script alternative

Tags: monitoring, loadrunner, vugen, sitescope, truclient

Not sure if iam asking this in the right place, sorry if not!

We currently create scripts through HP Virtual User generator (using the web click and script protocol) to monitor our webapps, we use this as they require JavaScript execution when being monitored. We import these scripts into HP sitescope so we get alerted when they are down.

The issue is after upgrading to loadrunner 12.01 they have removed the web click and script protocol. I have ran the protocol advisor and it advised to use Truclient ajax - IE protocol. I recorded a script using this and it worked great but it looks like this is not supported in sitescope!

Is anyone aware of an alernative to Web click and script that is compatible with sitescope or an alternative to sitescope altogether?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it is SiteScope and not BPM?

Answer (score 0):

Web virtual user.   Recode the JavaScript function you need in C or take advantage of the functions available in LoadRunner to execute your JavaScript "as is"

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to go with Web HTTP, as James suggests, here's the blog post that explains how to integrate JS bits into your script: **http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/HP-LoadRunner-and-Performance/How-to-use-JavaScript-in-your-HP-LoadRunner-scripts/ba-p/6197321#.VEO-f8ksHRw**

Answer (score 0):

They have not removed the click and script protocol. What they've done is rename it to Ajax Click and Script

Comment: Please be elaborate your answer. This is feel like a comment.

Comment: Sorry what I meant was the with LoadRunner 12.01 the Click and Script protocol has not been removed. In fact it has just been renamed to Ajax- Click and Script in the protocol selection when creating a new script. So the OP can still use loadrunner to create scripts using the click and script protocol they used before the upgrade.

Comment: Ajax click & Script existed in older versions so i assume it is something different. When i try to record with this it doesnt capture all the actions web click and script does. It only captures navigating to the site and not the login or navigation within

Answer (score 0):

Ah yes you're right Ajax Click and Script is different from the normal click and script that is no longer available in LR12.

With the  Ajax Click & Script have you tried changing the event configuration level? This might help.